# how to track begin ride using uber API

Tags: android, uber-api

I am planning on making an application which will run in parallel with uber app.
I want to do something after the begin ride is clicked.
Is there a way to do that ? How should I communicate with uber to know if driver has begun the ride ?

The app which I am planning will be installed on Driver's mobile.

Answer (score 0):

We currently do not have publicly available Driver API features. Thanks for expressing your interest! We always listen to our community in order to prioritize feature requests accordingly. Please stay tuned and check out our [Developer Blog for future API announcements](https://medium.com/uber-developers).

Having said that, I think you can still use our [Rides API Webhooks](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/webhooks) to implement this feature in your app. The Webhook feature sends out POST requests to your server-side application with updates on the status of the Uber ride request. In other words, you would be notified if the ride starts (implies that the driver clicked on Begin Trip).